# snapshots not being created at first test run

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, jestjs

The past week I have been trying to write some tests using Jest. I haven't had any trouble with basic assertions but when I tried to do some snapshots I ran into a wall. From my understanding, the first time you run the test a snapshot will be created, and after that it uses that snapshot to compare to the new snapshots. But when I run the test it fails and no snapshot is created. I have tried a few things but here is one code snippet...

```
import React from 'react';
import UserOptions from './UserOptions';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {store} from "../../redux/configureStore";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";


describe('the user options component', ()=>{
       it('should match snap shot', ()=>{
            const tree = renderer
                .create(<NavLink to="#"/>)
                .toJSON();
            expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
        }); // this fails
    });
```

I also get this error, but I don't know what to make of it...

> console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9194
>       The above error occurred in the  component:
>           in Route (created by NavLink)
>           in NavLink (at UserOptions.test.js:43)

I realize this might be a configuration problem, not a problem with the code. I have been researching everything I can think of and I'm not finding anything that is necessarily helpful. All suggestions are welcome at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) is a component that is part of [`react-router-dom`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

It is designed to be used inside of a wrapping [`Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router).

The `NavLink` component is designed to throw an error if it is rendered outside of a `Router`, and that is the error you are seeing when you attempt to render it on its own.

Because the `NavLink` throws an error as it is rendering, the test fails with that error and this line:

```
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

...is never reached so a snapshot is never created.